Vlan between vcenter and the kerio control
I have 15 vlans on my cisco switches and I have been create a trunk between the core switch and the vcenter. Also made a port group for each vlan. I want to have every vlans on kerio but I can't assign more than 10 interfaces to a virtual machine (kerio control). How should I solve the problem?
I made a port group by id 4095 on vSS and assgin it to the kerio control but on kerio I can't add vlan to this interface(that option is disable for this specific interface)

thanks for reply.
I did steps below and everything works fine.

shutdown the kerio Control machine.
assign Trunk(ID4095) port by adaptor type 1000E.
turn on the machine.


Please don't forget to eventually accept an answer. (And you may vote for any useful ones, too.)

VMware does not support more than 10 Virtual NICs per VM (Source).
I'm not familiar with Kerio, generally it should be possible to configure a portgroup with ID 0 (all VLANs) in VMware and then create virtual interfaces with the required VLANs inside the VM.
According to the documentation Kerio also supports this.

To access VLAN tags from within a guest you need to use a vSwitch port group with ID 4095. VMware calls this mode virtual guest tagging (VGT), see https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/8.0/vsphere-networking/GUID-7225A28C-DAAB-4E90-AE8C-795A755FBE27.html.
Then you need to configure VLANs on the guest, in Kerio, see the link in Gerald's answer.
I've had mixed success depending on the vNIC type, so you might want to try another one if it doesn't work - the Intel ones usually work best.
